# Website Looks Fine on Chrome Mobile Debug Version But Looks different on My Phone

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, google-chrome-devtools

Hello I finally finished my portfolio http://ruben123.com/ and I made sure the website is mobile friendly by using the chrome mobile view and adding all of the media queries needed for all mobile devices.

The problem when I look at my website on my phone it looks different.
Please see screenshots below. I have no idea what is causing this or how do I fix this?

I am using Scss for this project. Please see code & Screenshots below.

```
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <!-- MOBILE CSS -->

  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 768px)" href="css/mobile.css">

    <!-- Header -->
    <!-- <div id="header-home"> -->
    <div id="header-home">
      <!-- <div id="particles-js"></div> -->
      <div class="container">
        
        <!-- NAVBAR START -->
        <nav id="main-nav">
          <img src="img/logo-white-1.svg" alt="My Portfolio Logo" id="logo" />
          <!-- <i class="material-icons" id="mobile-menu">menu</i> -->

          <!-- DROP DOWN MENU - START -->

          <div class="menu-dropdown">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="con">
                <div class="bar top"></div>
                <div class="bar middle"></div>
                <div class="bar bottom"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="menu-content hidden">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#home" class="current">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#capabilities">Capabilities</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio-section">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#bottom-footer">Contact Me</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>


          <!-- DROP DOWN MENU - END -->


          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#home" class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about-me">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#capabilities">Capabilities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio-section">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#bottom-footer">Contact Me</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- NAVBAR END -->
    
        <div class="header-content">
          <h1>DESIGNER</h1>
          <h1>+</h1>
          <h1>DEVELOPER</h1>
          <p class="lead">
            Welcome to my website. I am a Graphic / Web Designer & Web Developer
          </p>
          


        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="particles-js"></div>
      <img
        src="img/bottom-curve.svg"
        class="bottom-curve"
        alt="bottom-header-curve"
      />
    </div>
    <!-- </div>  -->
    <!-- ABOUT ME -->
    <div id="about-me">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content-info">
          <h1 class="section-title">About Me</h1>
          <p class="lead">
            Hello my name is Ruben Esquivel and my dad was a graphic designer so
            I grew up playing with photoshop since I was a kid. For 10 years I
            worked as a remote graphic designer / web master running entire
            graphics department by myself providing mockups for getting sales
            and turning the mockups into print ready graphics to be printed. I
            am an expert in taking directions through phone or email and multi
            tasking multiple projects at once to meet the deadline. I can handle
            being under pressure and I am a master of hot keys so I can work
            fast when needed. After working in the industry for 10 years I felt
            like I knew everything when it came to graphic design so I decided
            to learn web development because I love learning new things. I love
            coding and I love taking my web designs and creating beautiful eye
            catchy websites. To be honest I love both graphic design and coding,
            being able to take an idea and turn into a design or website is like
            creating magic for me.
          </p>

          <div class="social-icons">
            <a href="mailto:rubenjr005@gmail.com" class="far fa-envelope"></a>
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/ruben-esquivel/" class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/rubenportfolio/" class="fab fa-instagram"></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/rubenjr005" class="fab fa-twitter"></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/Jr005" class="fab fa-github"></a>

          </div> 

        </div>
        <div class="profile-pic">
          <img
            class="p-2"
            src="img/ruben-profile-pic_01.png"
            alt="Ruben Profile Photo"
            class="ruben-profile-photo"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
  // #header

  #header-home {
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background: $dark-blue;
    z-index: 1;
    // position: relative;
    // background-image: image("/dist/img/Ellipse 1.svg");

    .bottom-curve {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -40px;
      width: 100%;
    }

    #particles-js {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      // background: $dark-blue;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 0;
    }

    .container {
      // z-index: 2;

      .header-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        text-align: center;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100%;
        // padding: 0 2rem;
        position: absolute;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        // padding-top: 20%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;

        h1 {
          font-size: 125px;
          line-height: 0.9;
          font-family: "Abril Fatface", cursive;

          // text-shadow:  0 0 10px #fff ;

          text-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
          // text-shadow: 0 0 5px #fff, 0 0 15px;
          // #fff, 0 0 20px #fff, 0 0 25px #fff, 0 0 30px #fff, 0 0 35px #fff;
          margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // About Me

  #about-me {
    margin-top: -3rem;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;

    .container {
      display: flex;
      overflow: visible;

      .content-info {
        flex: 2;

        // social icons

        .social-icons {
          font-size: 3rem;

          a {
            padding-right: 1rem;
            transition: color 0.5s;
          }

          a:hover {
            color: $yellow-color;
            // transition-delay: 0.25s;
          }
        }

        h1 {
          color: $light-blue;
        }
      }

      .profile-pic {
        flex: 1;
        margin-top: -5rem;
      }
    }
  }
```

MOBILE  MEDIA QUERIES CODE

```
      #header-home {
    margin-bottom: 7rem;
    .container {
      .header-content {
        h1 {
          font-size: 110px;
        }

        .lead {
          width: 80%;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  #about-me {
    //   margin-bottom: 0rem;
  }

  #capabilities {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }

  #skills .skills-container .skills-section .skills-list .dot:after {
    width: 150px;
  }

  // PORTFOLIO IMAGES

  #portfolio-section {
    .lightbox img {
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 800px;
      height: auto;
      margin-top: 20%;
    }
  }

  /* Smartphones */
  @media (max-width: 500px) {
    // MOBILE START

    #header-home {
      .container .header-content h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
      }

      .bottom-curve {
        bottom: -10px;
      }
    }

    //   ABOUT ME

    #about-me .container .profile-pic img {
      width: 80%;
    }

    //   CAPABILITIES

    #capabilities {
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
```

[image: Chrome Mobile View Screenshot]

[image: Chrome Mobile View]

My Phone iphone 8 Plus Screenshots.

[image: Mobile Screenshot]

[image: Mobile Screenshot 02]

Comment: We need to see your CSS

Comment: Ok I will edit this post.